# why Mergesort wall time is always 0? can someone help me pls...?

Tags: c, time, mergesort

I am trying to implement merge sort algorithm and somehow I always get `total_wall=0`? Can someone please help me? Is there somehow, I miss, because I already double check the result of the mergesort and the array is already sorted after the sorting and in the initialized state, the array is not yet unsorted?

Thank before for your help.

this is my code:

```
int sorting (void) {
    clock_t start_CPU, total_CPU;
    time_t start_Wall, end_Wall, total_Wall;

    start_CPU = clock ();
    start_Wall = time (NULL);

    sorting_partly(0, array_size - 1);

    end_Wall = time (NULL);
    total_CPU = clock () - start_CPU;
    total_Wall = difftime (end_Wall, start_Wall);

    printf ("total_cpu:\t %.3f \n", (float) total_CPU / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf ("total_wall:\t %.3f\n", (float) total_Wall);

    return 1;
}

int sorting_partly(int left, int right) {   
    int i = 0,accu = 0;
    int length = right - left + 1;
    int pivot  = (left + right) / 2;
    int merge1 = left, merge2 = pivot + 1;    
    int temp_array[length], temp_accu;

    if (left == right) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        sorting_partly (left, pivot); sorting_partly (pivot + 1, right);
    }

    for (accu = 0; accu <= pivot && accu + pivot + 1  <= right; accu++) {
        if (array_input[merge1] <= array_input[merge2]) {
            temp_array[accu] = array_input[merge1];
            merge1++;
        } else {
            temp_array[accu] = array_input[merge2];
            merge2++;
        }
    }

    for (temp_accu = merge1; temp_accu <= pivot; temp_accu++) {
        temp_array[accu] = array_input[temp_accu];
        accu++;
    }

    for (temp_accu = merge2; temp_accu <= right; temp_accu++) {
        temp_array[accu] = array_input[temp_accu];
        accu++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        array_input[i + left] = temp_array[i];
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: How large is `array_size`?

Comment: i already tried with 50000, 100000, and 1000000 Elements and i got all the same wall_time = 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
total_Wall = difftime (end_Wall, start_Wall);
```

total_Wall is of type time_t which is probably an integral type, whilst difftime returns a double. You are probably getting a warning that you are loosing precision. Try changing total_Wall to double or float and see what happens.

Comment: hi, Thank for the answers. somehow i try to print separately and i got the same value of end_wall and start_wall time? only sometime the different only 1 value?

Comment: That is, as NPE mentions above, because `time()` can only measure whole seconds, as an integer. It cannot measure anything less than seconds. Tha is why you have to use `clock()` or something else like [`std::chrono` in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Answer (score 1):

There are several potential issues:

1. `time()` returns the time *in seconds*, so it can't be used to measure short intervals.
2. `difftime()` returns `double`, and your code assigns the result to `time_t` (this can't really explain what you're seeing but IMO is worth fixing nonetheless).

Comment: Note that `difftime()` takes `time_t` arguments (i.e. integer seconds). So even if it returns `double` (and actually I don't know why it does), assigning the result to `time_t` does not make it worse.

Comment: @MartinR: Right. That's the essence of the parenthesised remark in my second point.